# Jokingly told my boss "I quit" on April Fools, and I think I just got fired

Tags: communication, resignation

I jokingly told my manager "I quit" via email (it was longer than that) as an April Fools joke. We get along pretty well normally.

Well, it seems my joke was taken a bit too seriously as I just got an automated email from HR with checkout procedures and an invite to a few "checkout" meetings  later this week as well. My company has also been letting a lot of people go recently so I am worried this is an excuse to have that happen to me.

I can see my manager responding in a like fashion but the HR communication worries me. He is also on vacation this week so I cannot ask him directly (which would be ideal).

- How can I determine if I am actually being fired or my boss is just playing along?

Comment: I guess you didn't follow up with an email saying "Just kidding! April Fool's!" I guess you could try to send that now, or slip it in during the interview. Also, maybe start updating your resume, just in case *they* aren't kidding.

Comment: Wait a minute... if your manager is on vacation, who told HR?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner now you understand why I'm worried.

Comment: If you got an *automated* email from HR, that would imply to me that they have been informed and have started the "terminate employment" process within their systems. If HR is "playing along" that's a pretty serious level of commitment to the prank. You need to speak to your boss ASAP.

Comment: @alroc - I dunno about that, I've never seen an HR department with a sense of humor.

Comment: Joke's on you I suppose XD
Boss: 'April Fools' he says... 'You're a fool in April' I'll reply

Comment: Does he have an administrative assistant? Perhaps that person forwarded the email to HR.

Comment: I think you should be fired for even entertaining the possibility that this would be an amusing april fools day joke.

Comment: The only way this joke gets really funny is if you commit to it. I say sell it to the hilt including with HR.  Maybe you can get to give you a bump in pay!

Comment: Am I the only person wondering if the joke is on enderland/enderland's boss, or everyone reading the question on workplace.se?

Comment: The next step is obviously to pretend you're planning to burn the building down. Keep the laughs rolling!

Comment: @NathanLong should I burn down just the building or the entire complex? I'm not really sure how to interpret your suggestion.

Comment: I can't tell if this post is the joke, or the people pretending to believe that you actually did this are the ones joking.

Comment: -1: It's now April 2nd. April Fools is long gone, you're the fool for carrying on, your grasp of time is not so hot, you're the fool and I am not!

Comment: so you were fired for having a bad taste in humour. Sometimes you can fight such a reason, but in this case your prior termination notice I'm afraid makes that rather unlikely to succeed. Best start looking for other employment.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The best plan of attack will be to [slap](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/boss-slapping-me-due-to-calc-error) your boss. [Slapping people](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6430/how-should-i-deal-with-being-slapped-at-work) at work is pretty common and will help make it more clear you were only joking.

If this doesn't work, [sleeping with your boss's wife](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7617/how-should-i-deal-with-an-employee-who-has-slept-with-my-wife) is also an effective way to make it clear you were only joking.

Failing that, you should probably [just quit](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/should-i-quit) your job - no one wants to work with a bunch of people who cannot take a joke.  This is likely to make it hard for you to get a new job.  Fortunately you can just [make up your new resume.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10770/is-it-ok-to-make-up-your-resume)  This will make is significantly easier to find a new job if they do not know to call your last one for a reference.

Make sure to watch out for an employee pushing you [in front of a bus](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9128/how-can-i-prepare-for-getting-hit-by-a-bus).

Comment: Gaaah, an april fools' joke about april fools? That belongs on meta.

Comment: Awesome collection of the workplace's greatest hits!

Comment: All good options, but don't forget about burning down your office. In the confusion your departure will be completely forgotten about...

Comment: Shouldn't such answers be Community Wiki?

Comment: @Carson63000 was that deliberate? 'Slapping' ... 'Greatest Hits'...? :D

Comment: The Q seems to be extracted directly from Dilbert, but I've just joined [workplace.se] so I could upvote this A ;) Excellent selection of reading material!

Answer (score 26):

Call your boss immediately and indicate in no uncertain terms that the email was a joke (an incredibly bad idea, by the way), and you're concerned that it was taken seriously.  The risk of being a sucker and falling for his automated HR email prank is much less disastrous than actually losing your job over a poorly thought out joke.

Answer (score 10):

There's no need to take action. Just carry on doing your job as well as you can. If your boss is playing along with your "joke," nothing will happen.

Mind you, if at some point in the future your pay stops being processed, you can be certain that they have "fixed the glitch" and you actually were terminated. Please be advised that if you resigned in writing, you were not fired. Your prank is in much the same taste as having a lawyer deliver divorce papers on April 1st.

Comment: which means no unemployment for you...

Comment: okay, so you're telling the OP off and purposefully giving him bad advice. Hmm. I'm sure this should have been a comment for these very reasons